# Conditional formatting based on comparison of two values

Tags: powerbi

I have created a table in which I have Project Name, its planned budget and its actual budget. 
I want to highlight those rows in which the actual budget is exceeding the planned budget.
Conditional Formatting is not helping in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet possible in Power BI. Related feature requests can be found here:

[Conditional formatting (cell highligh, font, etc) when comparing multiple fields](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19385893-conditional-formatting-cell-highligh-font-etc)

[Conditional Formatting - Whole Table Rows](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18159352-conditional-formatting-whole-table-rows)

Comment: I created a calculated column with this DAX `if(condition,"domain.com\right.png","domain.com\wrong.png")` and set its data category to Image Url.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to get my work around is a bit tricky and probably some people would disagree with me. However, I got the same problem.

What I have it was one data such is

```
StaffName   Date   ID   HrsBilled

Carl   2018-02-12  201923  8
Carl   2018-02-11  201923  6
Carl   2018-02-11  201923  6
Carl   2018-02-11  201923  3
Carl   2018-02-11  201923  12
Carl   2018-02-11  201923  2
```

and another data frame with the KPI

```
StaffName   ID   KPIHRS
Carl      201923     7
```

this is just a sample

then I merge both data frames just to get the positive or negative value by day.
that is what I was looking for.

Just adding a new column with the difference.

```
StaffName   Date   ID   HrsBilled   KPIHrs   Difference 

    Carl   2018-02-12  201923  8      7          1
    Carl   2018-02-11  201923  6      7         -1
    Carl   2018-02-11  201923  6      7         -1
    Carl   2018-02-11  201923  3      7         -4
    Carl   2018-02-11  201923  12     7          5
```

Then use color formatting with the new variable 
if X >= 0 Green
if X <  0 Reed 
[image]

all the best!